# Дистантная позиция частицы по отношению к вводному слову.

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:"**Никогда,кстати сказать, не мог себе представить, как ты выглядишь.Да и (,)признаться(,)не пытался.**"

Я знаю, что вводные слова, к котором относятся усилительные частицы,запятыми не выделяются.
Однако как поступить в этом случае?Неужели никаких знаков?

И еще вопрос:**нужно ли выделять вводное слово, ежели присутствует частица, но та находится на дистантной от него позиции?**

---

Пример:**"Может(,)твоя мама и знает правду, но она,думаю, повременит с наказанием."**

Предложение можно перестроить так:*"Твоя мама может и знает правду,но она,думаю,повременит с наказанием"*

Мне кажется,что пример не самый полноценный.Встречаю такие предложения,где вводные слова,по сути, относятся к частице,которые с легкостью можно перенести без потери смысла.

Comment: Проиллюстрируйте, пожалуйста, второй вопрос примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позвольте несколько подытожить полемику и высказать свое мнение.

*Да и, признаться,* ... или *да и признаться,* . Ставить или не ставить запятую перед вводными словом зависит от части речи *да и* .

Может ли это быть союзом? . Да, конечно. Присоединительный союз. Пусть даже после точки. Запятая нужна.

Может ли это быть частицей? Да, конечно. То, что ее нет в списках частиц, ещё ничего не значит. При определении морфологической принадлежности исходим не из "списков" (они могут быть разными в разных пособиях), а из функции слова. Можем ли мы заменить на "даже"(усилительную частицу)?  - Можем. Можем ли мы интонационно выделить, как и другие усилительные частицы? - Можем. Значит "да и " усилительная частица  - и запятая не нужна.

В очередной раз прихожу (и, надеюсь, привожу) к мысли,  что знаки препинания - это наши помощники на письме в понимании смысла, в передаче интонации, авторского замысла.

Comment: Все правильно!

Единственное насчет списка частиц. "По частям" она там есть. "Да" и "И" - частицы. так что буквоеды могут рассматривать как две рядом стоящие частицы. 

А в мысли о помощников убеждать не надо. Знаки для человека, а не человек для знаков.

Comment: Я никого не имею в виду персонально. Просто мне в своих ответах очень  часто приходится говорить о вариативности постановки знака, тогда как, я знаю, хочется однозначного ответа.

Comment: >>>Я никого не имею в виду персонально.  

Я тоже. А что, можно подумать иное?

Answer (score 3):

"Да и" - ***это союз. Присоединительный.*** Поэтому речи об усилительной частице при вводном слове быть не может. Выделяйте "признаться" запятыми на законных основаниях.

Comment: Докажите. А то на вас тут уже ссылаются.

Comment: Да? )))
Присоединительные союзы - и, да и, причём, притом, затем, отчего… Он учился хорошо, причём по всем предметам.http://www.rg.ru/2010/12/23/karnaukhova-site.html

Присоединительные: да, да и, тоже, также. Например: Решение Лизы сняло с его сердца камень, да и весь дом сразу ожил, точно от ниспосланного мира (Федин); Она мне нравилась все больше и больше, я тоже, по-видимому, был симпатичен ей (Чехов);http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/48.htm

Comment: Союз "да и" в исходном примере присоединяет конструкцию к уже завершённому высказыванию. Как бы вслед. "Да и"  можно заменить союзом "и": не мог себе представить и не пытался.

Comment: Извините, а при каких условиях "Да и" будет являться частицей?
 Как тогда поставить знаки?

Comment: Это не доказательство. Я просил обосновать, особенно вот эту часть: "Поэтому речи об усилительной частице при вводном слове быть не может". В крайнем случае объясните хотя бы примеры из Шаламова и Шолохова.  
    
>>>Да и" можно заменить союзом "и": не мог себе представить и не пытался.  
  
Вы соединили два предложения. В таком виде сомнений нет. Но в искхождном между предложениями точка. Поэтому и возникают подозрения насчет усилительной частицы.

Comment: Простите, я никак не предполагала, что мой ответ вызовет споры.  "Поэтому речи об усилительной частице при вводном слове быть не может" - конечно, я имела в виду только конкретное предложение "Да и (,)признаться(,)не пытался." Здесь речь о присоединительном союзе и вводном слове. Присоединительные союзы часто так и употребляются (после точки),они ПРИСОЕДИНЯЮТ добавочные замечания, не предусмотренные первоначальным планом высказывания.

Answer (score 1):

Мое мнение по расстановке знаков таково:

> Никогда, кстати сказать, не мог себе представить, как ты выглядишь. Да и, признаться, не пытался.

Если выкинуть слово "признаться", то запятые будут не нужны. На мой взгляд, "признаться" - вводное слово. А "да и" относится к "не пытался".

Comment: @behemothus, если посмотреть на пример №7 по-школьному, по-простому, то слово "признаться" оттуда просто так не выкинешь. Там действительно получается, что "да и признаться" является неделимой конструкцией. Касательно примера №3 мы не видим контекста в котором находится предложение.

Comment: P.S. насколько я понимаю, то согласно Розенталю, жесткого х-ра расстановки запятых между союзом и вводным словом нет. См. [здесь][1], §99 пп.6,7

 [1]: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

Comment: Я даже не обсуждаю (пока), правильно лди вы трактуете ситуацию.
Главное, что оба примера доказывают **принципиальную возможность** того, что "да и" является частицей.

Comment: Соглашусь. Почему Вы считаете, что частицей является конструкция "да и"?

Answer (score 0):

Никогда,кстати сказать, не мог себе представить как ты выглядишь. Да и,признаться,не пытался.

Comment: Нужна, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Это самое "да и" имеет отношение к "признаться" или к "не пытался"? Или для постановки запятой это не важно?

Answer (score 0):

Такое впечатление, что запятая перед "признаться" не нужна:

*Никогда, кстати сказать, не мог себе представить, как ты выглядишь. Да и признаться,не пытался.*
Нет под рукой справочников, но помнится, усилительная частица в начале предложения, за которой следеут вводное, составляет с этим вводым единое целое.

**нужно ли выделять вводное слово, ежели присутствует частица, но та находится на дистантной от него позиции**
Пример дайте. Я не могу представить услительную частицу в отрыве от усиливаемого ей слова или конструкции.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1.Надежда Кожевникова. Золушка // «Октябрь», 2003   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и, признаться, пугало: в сравнении с ее вдохновенным враньем реальность раскрылась бы во всем убожестве. [Надежда Кожевникова. Золушка // «Октябрь», 2003] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

2.Катя Костик. Животные осваивают Интернет (2002) // «Homes & Gardens», 2002.04.15   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и, признаться, забот с ними не оберешься. [Катя Костик. Животные осваивают Интернет (2002) // «Homes & Gardens», 2002.04.15] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

3.Алексей Варламов. Ночь славянских фильмов // «Новый Мир», 1999   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и признаться, несмотря на велеречивые рассуждения о презумпции невиновности, в действительности я побаивался здешних русских и, заслышав на улице родную речь, никогда не обнаруживал своего землячества ― а что, если впрямь напорюсь на каких-нибудь мафиози? [Алексей Варламов. Ночь славянских фильмов // «Новый Мир», 1999] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

4.Анатолий Найман. Любовный интерес (1998-1999)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и, признаться, от обиды, которая все-таки во мне сидела, от несильной, но неотлипающей ревности, от неприязни к ней из-за «мужиков», особенно из-за какого-то конкретного. [Анатолий Найман. Любовный интерес (1998-1999)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

5.Михаил Козаков. Актерская книга (1978-1995)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) ), из-за своих актерских амбиций, ввергнуть их обратно в московский быт, от которого они, да и, признаться, сам я, уже успели отвыкнуть? [Михаил Козаков. Актерская книга (1978-1995)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

6.Евгений Пермяк. Бабушкины кружева (1955-1965)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и, признаться, хотелось уехать от всего этого… [Евгений Пермяк. Бабушкины кружева (1955-1965)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

7.М. А. Шолохов. Судьба человека (1956)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и признаться, и сам я не охотник был на жалобных струнах играть и терпеть не мог этаких слюнявых, какие каждый день, к делу и не к делу, женам и милахам писали, сопли по бумаге размазывали. [М. А. Шолохов. Судьба человека (1956)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

8.Даниил Гранин. Искатели (1954)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Да и, признаться, когда занимаешься делом, не до умствований. [Даниил Гранин. Искатели (1954)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

9.Г. C. Эфрон. Дневники. Т. 1. 1940 (1940)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) В Голицыне мои одноклассники ко мне относились отлично, но, тем не менее, наши дружеские отношения не простирались за рамки класса: большинство из этих ребят живут в деревнях, да и, признаться, говорить с ними совершенно не о чем, кроме как о «классных» сюжетах. [Г. C. Эфрон. Дневники. Т. 1. 1940 (1940)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

10.Андрей Белый. Почему я стал символистом и почему я не перестал им быть во всех фазах моего идейного и художественного развития (1928)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Ни с кем из тогдашних символистов я не знаком; да и, признаться, не интересуюсь ими; они ― «декаденты» . [Андрей Белый. Почему я стал символистом и почему я не перестал им быть во всех фазах моего идейного и художественного развития (1928)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

....

Обратите внимание на примеры №№ 3 и 7.

Comment: Сверху было мнение, что "Да и" - это союз.

Comment: Было. И что?
Мнений может быть много, я не обязан со всеми соглашаться.
Вас, кстати, тоже уже двое попросили проиллюстрировать второй пример примером.

Comment: Я давно дал комментарий на сей счет.Простите, но я не твержу, что это действительно союз.Просто констатирую факт, что это упоминалось выше.

Comment: А четкого и вразумительного ответа мы так и не услышали(
Каждый думает по-своему и ссылается на свои источники.

Comment: Вы не услышали. Я услышал.